# iOS - How to silent/ringing iPhone within App

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Currently i am working on a task where i have to mute/ringing iPhone within app. I have found  [a link](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/source/browse/trunk/include/include/Celestial/AVSystemController.h?r=136/)! but developers say Apple forbids to use this Library in your app and they reject your app. Then how these app were developed ?  [Application 1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8) and [Application 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/auto-mute-by-location/id650303758?mt=8) If its possible can somebody guide me how to do this.
Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the reviews of those applications you should recognize the bad ratings. Some users say that the applications doesn't work. I had an similar problem and asked the Dev. at the Apple TechTalks. They said it's impossible and as you mentioned your app will be rejected.

Comment: we can do it by push notification by giving user a choice to either mute the ringer or left un mute when he enters a specified area you mentioned.

Comment: @Sadiq jep that is one way to handle it. I thought that you want so silent an ringing phone (incoming call) with your application. There is always the posibility to use APN without sound ("Silent notification")